# Is "propensity" only used for people?

Tags: word-usage, nouns

Do you like the use use of *propensity* when talking about

- tumors*
- seizures (as a result of a drug's side effect)
- companies
- countries

Or is it used only for people?

*Example: *Certainly we can't say whether the GMO maize increased the propensity for tumors.*

So far I have always used *propensity* when talking about people's tendency; habitual tendencies.

Comment: A propensity  is a natural tendency to do something. It may apply to people, animals but also countries. Tumours also may show a propensity : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tumors+with+a+propensity+&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctumors%20with%20a%20propensity%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Would you kindly give me an example sentence of tumor and propensity?

Comment: See examples here: https://www.google.it/search?q=%22tumors+with+a+propensity%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2003,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr&ei=IerFV8rxFISqsQGLiaDgBA

Comment: I've had a look at the example sentences and it looks like it isn't used very often - because it sounds wrong? It sounds good, it looks good but it is wrong. Isn't it like the word intrinsic which is overused and quite often misused?

Comment: Would a single source convince you?  In [this](http://www.uscupstate.edu/uploadedFiles/About_upstate/Planning_and_Organizational_Development/Training/Chain%20Saw%20Safety.pdf) safety manual for a chainsaw, we read these words on page 12:  "When you are holding the saw with only one hand on the handle like in the picture, the saw *has a propensity* to tip toward the leg."  (emphasis added).

Comment: I don't think it is wrong, a tumor , a mass of abnormal uncontrolled cells, may well show a "propensity" a "tendency"  to behave in a typical or atypical way.

Comment: the definition of innate is to behave in a particular way; habitual tendency or a strong inclination - according to the Oxford Dictionary.  There is nothing innate to the saw - it's the way _you_ are holding it. you may have propensity to hold it that way (because of stupidity). a saw is just a saw - it doesn't have a particular point of balance. If propensity is a habitual/innate tendency how can it apply to a chainsaw? People _are_ using it to mean likelihood. Perhaps the use of propensity in that chainsaw sentence is a moot point.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Josh61 How would _you_ use propensity in such a sentence?

Comment: @mscola1975 - in which sentence?

Comment: I want to make sure you understand that "the GMO maize increased the propensity for tumors" does not work.  There's no verb.  Better: "the GMO maize increased the incidence of tumors."

Comment: It can be fun to treat inanimate objects as though they had a will of their own.  My umbrella has an unfortunate propensity to open spontaneously.  (I made that up.  I'm not sure I currently own an umbrella.)  In my example, propensity = tendency.  Of your list, the one I would have to work pretty hard to use as a subject for propensity is "seizures", but I guess it can be done.  E.g. "in such and so conditions, my seizures have a propensity to ruin an otherwise agreeable afternoon."

Answer (score 1):

I would use it in all those cases - see the following definition from the Oxford Companion to Philosophy:

> **Propensity**
>
> A propensity is a probabilistic disposition of an object or person to
>   behave in a certain way—for example, the disposition of a radium atom
>   to undergo radioactive decay in a given time-period with a certain
>   degree of chance. Propensities are more firmly linked to behaviour
>   than mere tendencies are, because the mere tendencies of an object may
>   be counteracted by the contrary tendencies of other objects.
>
> Prof. E. J. Lowe

This suggests it is not confined to people but includes objects as well.